# @RawQuery with ViewModel

Tags: android, android-room, android-viewmodel

I followed this [Room With a View](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0) tutorial and everything works as expected. Now I'm trying to implement @RawQuery and display LiveData with ViewModel. I want to display a list of items that have a certain column value (in this case a String). In [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RawQuery) this code seems to be a solution for my desired app function:

```
@Dao
 interface RawDao {
     @RawQuery(observedEntities = User.class)
     LiveData<List<User>> getUsers(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
 }
 LiveData<List<User>> liveUsers = rawDao.getUsers(
     new SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM User ORDER BY name DESC"));
```

I want my read query to be constructed at run time when nameColumn value is passed into `simpleSQLiteQuery(String nameColumn)` function which returns `new SimpleSQLiteQuery`.

Here is my code:

**Dao**

```
@Dao
public interface ShotDao {

@RawQuery(observedEntities = Shot.class)
LiveData<List<Shot>> getNameColumn(SupportSQLiteQuery supportSQLiteQuery);

}
```

**Repository**

```
    private ShotDao mShotDao;
    private LiveData<List<Shot>> mNameColumn;
    private SimpleSQLiteQuery mSimpleSQLiteQuery;

    public ShotRepository(Application application) {
        WrappShotDatabase database = WrappShotDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mShotDao = database.shotDao();
        mNameColumn = mShotDao.getNameColumn(mSimpleSQLiteQuery);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Shot>> getNameColumn (SimpleSQLiteQuery simpleSQLiteQuery) {
        this.mSimpleSQLiteQuery = simpleSQLiteQuery;
        return mNameColumn;
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
    private ShotRepository mRepository;
    private LiveData<List<Shot>> mNameColumn;
    private SimpleSQLiteQuery mSimpleSQLiteQuery;

    public ShotViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new ShotRepository(application);
        mNameColumn = mRepository.getNameColumn(mSimpleSQLiteQuery);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Shot>> getNameColumn (SimpleSQLiteQuery simpleSQLiteQuery) {
        this.mSimpleSQLiteQuery = simpleSQLiteQuery;
        return mNameColumn;
    }
```

**Activity**

```
        String columnName = mColumnName;

        shotViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ShotViewModel.class);
        shotViewModel.getNameColumn(simpleSQLiteQuery(columnName)).observe(this, new Observer<List<Shot>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Shot> shots) {
                mShotAdapter.submitList(shots);
            }
        });
```

**SimpleSQLiteQuery method**

```
 private SimpleSQLiteQuery simpleSQLiteQuery(String nameColumn) {
        String select = "SELECT * FROM ";
        String tableName = "shots";
        String where = " WHERE nameColumn=\"";
        String close = "\"";
        return new SimpleSQLiteQuery(select + tableName + where + nameColumn + close);
    }
```

When Activity is created my app crashes and I get an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.arch.persistence.db.SupportSQLiteQuery.getSql()' on a null object reference
```

I don't quiet understand why my object is not created and when It should be. Logcat also points out row A and row B in ShotDao_Impl.java generated source file.

```
@Override
  public LiveData<List<Shot>> getNameColumn(SupportSQLiteQuery supportSQLiteQuery) {
    final SupportSQLiteQuery _internalQuery = supportSQLiteQuery;
    return new ComputableLiveData<List<Shot>>() { // row A
      private Observer _observer;
      @Override
      protected List<Shot> compute() {
        if (_observer == null) {
          _observer = new Observer("shots") {
            @Override
            public void onInvalidated(@NonNull Set<String> tables) {
              invalidate();
            }
          };
          __db.getInvalidationTracker().addWeakObserver(_observer);
        }
        final Cursor _cursor = __db.query(_internalQuery); // row B
        try {
          final List<Shot> _result = new ArrayList<Shot>(_cursor.getCount());
          while(_cursor.moveToNext()) {
            final Shot _item;
            _item = __entityCursorConverter_comExampleAndroidWrappDatabaseShot(_cursor);
            _result.add(_item);
          }
          return _result;
        } finally {
          _cursor.close();
        }
      }
    }.getLiveData();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in viewmodel gives you error. You are setting `mSimpleSQLiteQuery` for room db which is null.

`mNameColumn = mRepository.getNameColumn(mSimpleSQLiteQuery);`

You should remove line above from viewmodel and modify `getNameColumn()` function like this:

```
public LiveData<List<Shot>> getNameColumn (SimpleSQLiteQuery simpleSQLiteQuery) {
    return mRepository.getNameColumn(mSimpleSQLiteQuery);;
}
```

**Edit:**

You can simplify your code by modifying your DAO. You can pass parameters straight into DAO.

E.g.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM shots WHERE nameColumn = :columnName")
LiveData<List<Shot>> getNameColumn(String columnName);
```

with this function you can retrieve `shots` according to column name

Comment: Thank you for solution and simplification example!

Answer (score 0):

The `mNameColumn` LiveData in ViewModel is created with a `null` `mSimpleSQLiteQuery` while the ViewModel constructor is executed. YOu are setting this in `getNameColumn` but take note that your livedata has no knowledge of this new value.

Hence the impl of `ShotDao` for `LiveData<List<Shot>> getNameColumn(SupportSQLiteQuery supportSQLiteQuery);` receives `null` SupportSQLiteQuery which results in crash.